# How do I return the first matched result in each folder with find command in tcsh?

Tags: command-line, find

I want to find all `.mb` files in multiple big folders, but I only want to return one file from each folder if there are many files matching my search criterion.

folder structure

```
..
--abc
    |_scenes
    |    |__  file1.mb
    |    |__  file2.mb
    |...
--def
    |_scenes
    |    |__  file3.mb
    |    |__  file4.mb
    |...
```

if I do

```
find /net/*/scenes -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +200M
```

It returns all

```
file1.mb
file2.mb
file3.mb
file4.mb
```

How can I return only `file1.mb` and `file3.mb`?

Comment: I updated my solution to use `find` instead of a `bash` loop - double `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`find`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
find /net/*/scenes -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.mb" \
| awk -F'/' '{ fn = $NF; $NF = "" }!a[$0]++{ print $0 fn }' OFS='/'
```

- `-F'/'` and `OFS='/'` - stand for input and output field separator
- `fn = $NF` - storing the last field value (i.e. a filename) into variable `fn`
- `!a[$0]++{ print $0 fn }` - on the 1st occurrence of unique directory path (presented by `$0`) print the line(the whole filepath)

---

Or using GNU `coreutils` pipeline:

```
find /net/*/scenes -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.mb" -printf "%H %p\n" \
| sort -k1,1 -u | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Comment: thanks! can you explain the `awk` part?

Comment: @Shuman, see my explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your new edit specifies that you're using `tcsh` - I'd originally assumed you were using `bash`. You could call `find` from within a `find -exec` invocation and pipe each internal `find` invocation to `head` to extract the first result, e.g.

```bsh
find /net/* -maxdepth 1 -exec tcsh -c "find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mb' -size +200M | head -1" \;
```

Here's a little example demonstration:

```bsh
# Create the directory structure
mkdir -p test/abc/scenes
mkdir -p test/def/scenes

# Create example data files
dd if=/dev/zero of=abc/scenes/file1.mb bs=201M count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=abc/scenes/file2.mb bs=201M count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=def/scenes/file3.mb bs=201M count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=def/scenes/file4.mb bs=201M count=1

# Execute the find command
find ./* -maxdepth 1 -exec tcsh -c "find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mb' -size +200M | head -1" \;
```

This yields the following output:

```
./abc/scenes/file1.mb
./def/scenes/file3.mb
```

---

Originally the question didn't specify `tcsh`. In `bash`, you could call `find` from within a loop and pipe each `find` invocation to `head` to extract the first result, e.g.

```bsh
for directory in /net/*/scenes; do
    find "${directory}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mb' -size +200M | head -1;
done
```

Here's a little example demonstration:

```bsh
# Create the directory structure
mkdir -p test/abc/scenes
mkdir -p test/def/scenes

# Create example data files
dd if=/dev/zero of=abc/scenes/file1.mb bs=201M count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=abc/scenes/file2.mb bs=201M count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=def/scenes/file3.mb bs=201M count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=def/scenes/file4.mb bs=201M count=1

# Execute the find command
for directory in ./*/scenes; do
    find "${directory}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mb' -size +200M | head -1;
done
```

This yields the following output:

```
./abc/scenes/file1.mb
./def/scenes/file3.mb
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 find commands first to find directories, then to search in each of them:

```
while read dir; do find "$dir" -name "*.mb" -maxdepth 1 | head -1 ; done << EOF
$(find /net/*/scenes -type d)
EOF
```